# Can't access inverse in too-many relationship child

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a bit of a circular CoreData structure.

Say you have `Step`, and each `Step` can have `substeps`. Since `substep` has all the same properties as a `Step`, the type is reused, and `Steps` is a property of `Manual`

But not all `Step` have `substeps`, some exist on their own.

So on a `Step` that exists on its own, `step.manual` resolves fine, but on a substep, it returns `nil`.

[image]

So if I'm in a `Step`, which is from an `NSSet` on a parent `Step`, how do I access the manual?

Comment: You need a `parentStep` inverse in `Step`

Comment: I agree with the above but from the image it also looks like the relationship between Step and Step is many-to-many, is this really what you want? Can one step be the sub step of several different steps?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to have a `parentStep` in `Step`, and traversing upwards until I found a `Step` with a `manual`